# How can html text be partially validated in Cypress?

Tags: cypress

I would like to validate or assert the text inside the div element of the following html has the correct email id

**The html snippet is as follows:**

```
<div _ngcontent-mpt-c200="" class="welcome-msg"> 
Hi, Welcome to our blog, dummyuser@test.com (
<a _ngcontent-mpt-c200="" class="pointer">not Dummy User?
</a>) 
</div>
```

**My cypress assertion is:**

```
cy.get('.welcome-msg').invoke('text').should('include.text', 'dummyuser@test.com')
```

**I get this error:**

Timed out retrying after 4000ms: You attempted to make a chai-jQuery assertion on an object that is neither a DOM object or a jQuery object.

The chai-jQuery assertion you used was:

> text

The invalid subject you asserted on was:

> Hi, Welcome to our blog, dummyuser@test.com (not Dummy User?)

To use chai-jQuery assertions your subject must be valid.

**I also tried using:**

```
cy.get('.welcome-msg').should('contain.text', 'dummyuser@test.com')
```

**and this:**

```
cy.get('.welcome-msg').invoke('html.text').then(userInfoText => {
            userInfoText.should('contain.text', 'dummyuser@test.com')
        })
```

Has anyone got an idea on how to make this assertion work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your first attempt you invoked the `text()` to get the text of the jQuery element followed by an assertion that essentially does the same thing before asserting the text.

You can do either of two things with your first attempt.

```js
cy.get('.welcome-msg').should('include.text', 'dummyuser@test.com')
```

or

```js
cy.get('.welcome-msg').invoke('text').should('include', 'dummyuser@test.com')
```